# How to easily test POSTs when making a website?

Tags: testing, post

What's an easy way to test sending POST requests when making a website? I can easily send GET requests by typing it in the URL (`example.com/?foo=bar&bar=baz`) but what's an equivalently easy way to send POST requests?

Comment: Why not create a form with a post action ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or a Browser plugin like [FireFox Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/).

Or you can just create a form and submit it from any .HTML page:

```
<form action="TestPage.html" method="POST">
    <input name="name1" value="value1" />
    <input name="name2" value="value2" />
    <input type="submit" value="POST!" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can even submit it from your desktop

Answer (score 11):

Curl CLI

```
curl -d "param1=value&param2=value2" http://www.example.com/resource
```

or

```
curl -F "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://www.example.com/resource
```

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl/149335#149335

But I always just use a test script with a http request class. I find you get finer granularity over headers, formats, verb, etc. And of course you can put that code into a unit test after you're done. I use this class that I wrote ( https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.md ) but I hear that the zend request class is quite good too.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know firebug could send post requests

Answer (score 1):

you can use any inspector to do that like fireFox

make request type post >> put your url >> put parameters in request body section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try some http request sending tools like Wfetch

Answer (score 0):

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) in Google Chrome, is a great tool to test POST methods.

Comment: thought it's for backend only?